# How to edit picture on Coudinary with Laravel

Tags: laravel, api, storage, edit, cloudinary

Any Idea how to edit pictures on Cloudinary using Laravel API? I did a lot of searches, but I didn't find any references. The add worked successfully, but I didn't find a solution for the edit.

**Add code**

```
$user->user_image = Cloudinary::upload(
    $request->file('user_image')->getRealPath(),
    [
        'folder' => 'Testing'
    ]
)->getSecurePath();
```

**Attempt at updating picture**

```
public function updatePicture(Request $request, $user_id)
{
    $data = $request->validate([
        'user_image' => '',
    ]);

    $data = Cloudinary::upload(
        $request->file('user_image')->getRealPath(),
        [
            'folder' => 'Testing'
        ]
    )->getSecurePath();
    
    User::where("user_id", $user_id)->update($data);

    return response()->json([
        'message' => 'Successfully updated Picture!',
        'success' => true,
    ], 200);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For deleting, you can use the `destroy()` method of the API, for example:

```
$result = Cloudinary::destroy(
        $public_id, //Public ID of the file from Cloudianry to delete - returned from the Upload API response
        [
            '...' => '...' //any optional parameters
        ]
    )
```

For a list of all optional parameters and possible values please see:
https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_upload_api_reference#destroy_method

In terms of updating, I am assuming you are referring to Cloudinary's [update details of a single resource](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/admin_api#update_details_of_an_existing_resource) method of the [Admin API](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/admin_api). If so, you can access it like so:

```
$admin_api = Cloudinary::admin();
$result = $admin_api->update($public_id, $options = []);
```

Alternatively, if you're referring to the [explicit](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_upload_api_reference#explicit) method of the [Upload API](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_upload_api_reference) then you could access it like so:

```
$result = Cloudinary::explicit($public_id, $options = []);
```

Comment: @Aleksander I want to edit not delete

Comment: @stackuser - I have updated the answer with details about the update() and explicit() methods.